# Select common elements for 2 or more departments from list group by then having count

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I have a class that looks like so:

```
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int DepId{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data that my list folds looks like so:

```
ID  |  Name     |  CategoryId  |  DepId
---------------------------------------
1   |  Post     |  1           |  1
2   |  Post     |  1           |  2
3   |  Printer  |  2           |  1
4   |  Printer  |  2           |  3
5   |  Post     |  3           |  3
6   |  Printer  |  2           |  1
```

This data holds Access data to some categories.

What I would like to get is common categories for 2 (or more) departaments

If user selects that he want categories for department with id=1 then he should get elements with id 1 and 3, but if he wants categories for department 1 and 3 he should get elements 4 and 6.

For DepId IN(1,3) I would like to get this result:

```
Name     |  CategoryId
----------------------
Printer  |  2
```

Something like JOIN in SQL.

I was able to code it in sql:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT  
    C.Cat_Id AS Id,
    MAX(C.Name) AS Name,
FROM 
    Categories_Access AS CA (NOLOCK)
    JOIN dbo.Categories AS C (NOLOCK) ON C.Cat_Id = CA.Cat_Id
WHERE 
    CA.DepId IN (1,3)
    GROUP BY C.Cat_Id
    HAVING COUNT(*)=2
) A ORDER BY A.Name
```

Now I would like to do same thing in C#.

**EDIT**
This is my attempt:

```
var cat = new List<Category>();
            cat.Add(new Category {Id = 1, CategoryId = 1, Name = "Post", DepId = 1});
            cat.Add(new Category {Id = 2, CategoryId = 1, Name = "Post", DepId = 2});
            cat.Add(new Category {Id = 3, CategoryId = 2, Name = "Printer", DepId = 1});
            cat.Add(new Category {Id = 4, CategoryId = 2, Name = "Printer", DepId = 3});
            cat.Add(new Category {Id = 5, CategoryId = 3, Name = "Another", DepId = 3});
            cat.Add(new Category {Id = 6, CategoryId = 2, Name = "Printer", DepId = 1});
            cat.Add(new Category {Id = 7, CategoryId = 4, Name = "Else", DepId = 1});

            var ids = new List<int> {1, 2};

            var Query = from p in cat.Where(i => ids.Contains(i.DepId)).GroupBy(p => p.CategoryId)
                        select new
                        {
                            count = p.Count(),
                            p.First().Name,
                            p.First().CategoryId
                        };
```

[image]

What I need to do is just to select items that have count=ids.Count.

My finale version (based on @roughnex answer):

```
private static IEnumerable<Cat> Filter(IEnumerable<Category> items, List<int> ids)
{
    return items.Where(d => ids.Contains(d.DepId))
   .GroupBy(g => new { g.CategoryId, g.Name })
   .Where(g => g.Count() == ids.Count)
   .Select(g => new Cat { Id = g.Key.CategoryId, Name = g.Key.Name });
}
```

Comment: Have you set up the two tables you are joining in either a LINQ to SQL (DBML) or Entity Framework (EDMX) model?

Comment: I have list of `Category` objects already inside my app, they come from SQL procedure. What I want now is to query that list for common categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# (LINQ) to select common elements you ll use

```
List<int> Depts = new List<int>() {1, 3};


var result = Categories.Where(d => Depts.Contains(d.DeptId))
                       .GroupBy(g => new {g.CatId, g.Name})
                       .Where(g => g.Count() >= 2)
                       .Select(g => new {g.Key.CatId, g.Key.Name});
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on what you've said, you've already parsed the data from a SQL proc into a `List<Category>`.  If that is the case, the following snippet should guide you:

```
var items = new List<Category>();

var deptIds = new List<int>() { 1, 3 };

var query = items.Where(item => deptIds.Contains(item.DepId))
            .Select(category => category);
```

When you want to do an IN in LINQ, you have to invert it and use Contains.  Whereas in SQL it's ColumnName IN (List), in LINQ it's List.Contains(ColumnName).  Hope that helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I have in mind. I've added my version of solution to my question, I'm newbie if it comes to LINQ so I can't figure rest of query.